# Cannot delete or update a parent row constraint violation with cascade remove

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, model, symfony4

I have 2 entites : **Information** and **PossibleAnswer**
**Information** can be seen as a question, depending on its type, it can have **PossibleAnswers**. It can also have a child **Information**, if the parent **Information** has **PossibleAnswers**, one of them will trigger the child dipslay.

**Information** class :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\InformationRepository")
 */
class Information
{

    use DateTrait;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\PossibleAnswer", mappedBy="information", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $possibleanswers;

    /**
     * One Information has Many Informations.
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Information", mappedBy="parent", cascade={"remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"rank" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $children;

    /**
     * Many Informations have One Information.
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Information", inversedBy="children")
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * réponse qui déclenche une sous question
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PossibleAnswer")
     */
    private $trigger;
```

**PossibleAnswer** class :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PossibleAnswerRepository")
 */
class PossibleAnswer
{

    use DateTrait;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Information", inversedBy="possibleanswers")
     */
    private $information;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $value;
```

Now I want to delete a specific Information and delete every PossibleAnswer or child Information. But some delete cases are not working :

1. Single Information : OK
2. Information with child Information : OK
3. Information with PossibleAnswers : OK
4. Information with PossibleAnswers triggering a child Information : **KO**
5. Information with child Information whit PossibleAnswers : **KO**

In case 4 :

> An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM possible_answer
>   WHERE id = ?' with params [28]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or
>   update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`evisa`.`information`, CONSTRAINT `FK_297918835FDDDCD6` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`trigger_id`) REFERENCES `possible_answer` (`id`))

In case 5 :

> An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM information WHERE
>   id = ?' with params [56]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or
>   update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`db`.`possible_answer`, CONSTRAINT `FK_3D79739D2EF03101` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`information_id`) REFERENCES `information` (`id`))

I'm missing something in my cascading to delete everything correctly, but I can't find what it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using ORM level cascades, what you are trying to achieve is Database Level cascade http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/6s4g/one-to-many-association-cascade-example-with-doctrine-annotations
What you need is `onDelete="CASCADE"`
For example:

`/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Information", inversedBy="possibleanswers")
 * @JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
*/
private $information;`

Always use JoinColumn you will have more control over your code and manually name columns, otherwise you will end up with a mess in your database, some names will be CamelCase some snake_case.

Answer (score 1):

For deleting OneToMany relation data from the database, you need to follow the below instructions
**1- You need to create your delete function in YourController**

```
#[Route('/{id}/delete', name: 'information_delete', methods: ['GET'])]
Public function delete(Information $information, InformationRepository $informationRepository): Response
{
    $informationRepository->remove($information, true);
    return $this->redirectToRoute('information_index');// Your list route
}
```

**2- You need add or change in Information entity (Entity\Information.php)**

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *      targetEntity="PossibleAnswer", // Second Entity name
 *      mappedBy="information",
 *      cascade={"persist", "remove"}
 * )
 */
protected $possibleanswer; // This is value of inversedBy in PossibleAnswer entity
```

**3- You need add or change in PossibleAnswer entity (Entity\PossibleAnswer.php)**

```
#[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'possibleanswer', targetEntity: Information::class)]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(name:"information_id",referencedColumnName:"id",onDelete: "CASCADE", nullable: false)]
protected $information; //This is value of mappedBy in Information entity
```

**4- You have to apply migration after these changes

```
php bin/console make:migration  
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```